# Applying a function many-to-many using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `pandas` to do some conditional filtering based on string matching using the `fuzzywuzzy` module. I've written some code that works, but is painfully slow and goes against every instinct in my body because I'm using a for loop over a pandas Series.

My issue is that I want to compare array of strings to another, and if a string in one array is similar enough to ANY string in the other array, I want to remove it from the array completely. My current code is this:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd
for value in new_contacts['StringMatch']: # this is a pandas column in a dataframe
    previous_contacts['ratio'] = previous_contacts['StringMatch'].apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x, value))
    previous_contacts = previous_contacts[previous_contacts['ratio'] > 97] # fuzz.ratio outputs an int between 0 and 100
    previous_contacts.drop('ratio', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions / best practices to make this code faster?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a faster way to do what you are asking. If possible, I'd ask you to reevaluate your need for the fuzzywuzzy package. The edit distance computation is very expensive as it constructs a matrix of size `n * m` (`n` and `m` being the sizes of the two strings) for each pair of strings in your arrays.